# How to use get the current directory and use wildcard to find any csv file there?

Tags: powershell

How can I use relative path and relative (wildcard) files in powershell?

I have tried the following but didn't work:

```
Powershell -c
 $file= Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv
 [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText .\$file .replace('Buyer','Alıcı').
replace('Supplier','Tedarikçi').
replace('FI','Banka').
replace('Supplier Reference','Tedarikçi Referansı').
replace('Buyer Program','Alıcı Programı').
replace('Buy Offer','eklif Al').
replace('Payment Obligation Id','Ödeme Yükümlülüğü Kimliği').
replace('Buyer Unique Doc Id','Alıcı Benzersiz Doküman Kimliği').
replace('Trade Date','Ticaret Tarihi').
replace('Due Date','ödeme tarihi').
replace('Maturity Date','Vade Tarihi').
replace('Currency','Para Birimi').
replace('Certified Value','Sertifikalı Değer').
replace('Buyer Payment Amount','Alıcıya Ödeme Tutarı').
replace('Buyer Fee','Alıcı Ücreti').
replace('Supplier Interest Fees','Tedarikçi Faiz Ücretleri').
replace('Supplier Funds Received','Alınan Tedarikçi Fonu')|sc c:\pstest\test2.csv
```

I want the script to fetch for any csv file in the same directory where the script is being run, any ideas?

Comment: The term "current directory", in PS lingo, refers to the lst directory  selected to be current.  This is what dot resolves to.  So  ./*.jpg  ought to give you all the jpg files in the current directory.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It's exactly what I mean, but I have tried ./*.csv but didn't work.

Comment: What did it do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of suggestions how to get path of running script. 
Althought I would do that like this:

```
 $dir = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
 $dir = $dir.SubString(0, $dir.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
```

Then you got path of script execution and what you need is just to call your script.

```
 . $dir"MyScript.ps1"
```

Comment: So $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path gets the path where the script is being executed?  Also why do I need to use . $dir"MyScript.ps1"; this script would be already running, what i want is to find the csv file where it's just in the same folder.